# Knp Paginator setUsedRoute not working correctly

Tags: symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I am using the Knp Paginator and for some reason when I set the setUsedRoute() it is not using any elements inside of the array. Here is my code:

```
$pagination->setUsedRoute(
    'page_data',
    array(
        'name'=>$artist[0]->getNameSlug(),
        'hook'=>$hook 
    )
);
```

> It should render the route as /page/data/cold-play/store
>
> But its only rendering the route as /page/data///

I have verified that both $artist[0]->getNameSlug() & $hook are NOT null.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the full code you are using before and after `setUsedRoute()` method?